# euler-lagrange equation expansion

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

Euler-Lagrange equation

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 0$$

Can also be written as

$$f'_y-f''_{xy'}-f''_{yy'}y'-f''_{y'y'}y''=0$$

In my book it is provided as a self-evident fact. It is not evident to me at all. Please help me with the derivation, I have no idea where to even start

Answer (score 0):

$y=y(x)$, $f=f(x,y,y')$. Then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=\frac{d}{dx}y'_{y'}(x,y,y')=
f''_{xy'}+f''_{yy'}y'+f''_{y'y'}y''$$